# プレハブ化したオブジェクト（ボタン）のスクリプト

Tags: unity3d, ugui

Unity を始めてからまだ５日の初心者です。初歩的な内容で申し訳ありませんが、プレハブについて教えてください。

あるボタンにクリックイベントを作成してスクリプトをインスペクタしたあとそのボタンをプレハブ化するとイベントやスクリプトがなくなってしまうのはプレハブ化における普通の出来事なのでしょうか？
　
プレハブは再利用可能な部品という概念ならば、スクリプトもプレハブに組み込まれると思っていたのですが…。

よろしくご指導ください。

Answer (score 1):

状況を正確に把握できていないかもしれませんが、おそらく「スクリプトをアタッチしたGameObjectがプレハブに含まれていない」のが原因ではないかと推察します。

プレハブ化するボタン自体にスクリプトをアタッチするか、スクリプトをアタッチしたGameObjectをボタンの子供にする(入れ子にする)など、スクリプトをアタッチしたGameObjectをプレハブに含めれば解決するものと考えます。

一応手元で簡単なプロジェクトでご質問の現象が起きることと、上記方法で解決することを確認しました。よろしければお試しください。

Comment: 回答いただきまして有難うございました！

確かにスクリプトがアタッチされてなければ

イベントだけアタッチしても無理ですよね

やってみたらできました。有難うございました。